# Scala: Function definition of PartialFunction is ambiguous

Tags: scala, partialfunction

Function definition of the PartialFunction is following:

```
trait PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends (A) ⇒ B
```

PartialFunction would allow us to filter by using `case` with `collect` on collection. 
For example when you have list of integers and PartialFunction isEven[Int, String] which will convert to String if the value in the collection is even number. So it returns a new collection with the return type `+B`in the definition.

My question is, why `contravariant -A` and `covariance +B`? It basically has ability to accept any input to any output. Why do we need to indicate the input should be a any type or super type of a type A and return type should be B or its subclass? Can't we just say:

```
trait PartialFunction[A, B]
```

Comment: By the way, this rule of covariance/contravariance in functions holds not only in scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does **not** "basically allow it to accept any input to any output". Co- and contravariance are not trivial (in the mathematical sense) relations, they are strictly defined by the bound type - as you probably realize.

This specific form of type bounds, i.e. contravariance of arguments and covariance of the return type is a general phenomenon, not limited to Scala, and **comes from the notion of [function types from formal type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping_of_functions#Function_types), specifically:**

> If T1 → T2 is a function type then a subtype of it is any function S1 → S2 with the property that T1 <: S1 and S2 <: T2.

**allowing for a well-defined subtyping relation of said function types.**

Comment: My question is for partial function, why co-contra variances were noted as is. Some example would be helpful.

Comment: For exactly the same reason as non-partial functions. Why would you expect them to be different?

Comment: @Mayumi : exactly as Alexey said. Or do you need a general example?